# Array length in HLSL?

Tags: loops, shader, hlsl

I can't find any docs or examples on how to get the length of an array in HLSL.

I push an array of lights to an hlsl shader and I want to do a `for(int i=0; i<foo.length; i++)` (- not the correct syntax).

Is it not possible to obtain the length of an array? Must I push an array length integer to the hlsl shader from the c++ side?

Additionally, how can I find out what's the maximum allowed for-loop count I can have in my shader? (Since loops are unrolled, there should be a limit.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to declare arrays with a predefined length ([Array syntax needs a positive integer as size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509706(v=vs.85).aspx)). If you now fill this fixed array from extern with an arbitrary amount of data, HLSL has no way to know about this. So you need to pass a the array length to the shader.

Loop aren't automatically unrolled, if you are working with shader model 3.0+ and not specify `[unroll]` in before. ([doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509602(v=vs.85).aspx))

> When no attribute is specified the compiler will first attempt to emit a rolled version of the loop, and if that fails, or if some operations would be easier if the loop was unrolled, will fall back to an unrolled version of the loop.

So there is no maximum allowed loop count, but dependent on your used shader model, there is a maximum executed instruction count ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Shading_Language)) and additionally there is a watchdog of windows resetting your graphic device if it need more than 2 seconds for rendering ([doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570087(v=vs.85).aspx)), for example with infinite loops.

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense. The hlsl array is not a structure that magically holds a length value. In my case I was sending resources to the shader via the Unreal Engine C++ side which makes those particular arrays available "magically" and invisibly in the shader code.